# How to create browser extension to show infobar-like HTML form banner in Firefox and Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, forms, banner

I would like to create a browser extension which will show a persistent infobar-like banner in Google Chrome or Firefox web browser. This banner should push the website down so as to not block any content in the website.

I would like to put a HTML form in the infobar banner, with some radio buttons, textboxes, dropdown boxes, and button to submit the HTML form's data. I would like to make the infobar banner persistent across webpages, i.e. user can browse to other webpages but the infobar banner will stay at the top of the browser window.

When user click the button and submit the HTML form, the infobar should bounce up and then bounce down to show a new infobar with a new HTML form.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to create this kind of infobar banner in Google Chrome or Firefox browser?

I have searched for the browser API but so far I have only found the [Google Chrome Infobar](http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/infobars) function. It seems that it can only show 1 line of notification.

Comment: Do you want this in the chrome or in the document?

Comment: Does "in the chrome" means part of the grey browser window? Actual it is ok to put it as part of the browser window or the HTML document. I just want to have a infobar banner which can be used to submit HTML form and it should not affect the website below the infobar banner. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. For Google Chrome, [you'd need to inject script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6681697/1615483) into the current document - you can't put it into the chrome. For Firefox you can, but you'll have to write it in XUL (similar to XHTML); see a tutorial like this: http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/

Comment: Hi Paul, please put your answer into the Answer section so that I can select it as the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Google Chrome; [you'd need to inject script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6681697/1615483) into the current document - you can't put it into the chrome. Read more about content scripts for Google Chrome [**here**](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).
- Firefox; you can, but you'll have to write it in [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XUL) (similar to XHTML); see a tutorial like [**this**](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/).

If you want something that works on both, go down the content script route as it could easily be ported to FireFox as a [**userscript**](http://userscripts.org/about/installing).

Answer (score 3):

As far as Google Chrome goes, it would appear that, as of 2014, there is now finally a [`chrome.infobars`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/infobars.html) API available in Chrome.

For more details, see

- [How to make a toolbar in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681697/how-to-make-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome/17279590#17279590)
- [Release schedule of chrome.infobars Chome Toolbar API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21512026/1122270)

Comment: Note that as of June 21, 2014, it only works on the Dev branch.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, yes, according to the "Release schedule" question as above, it is currently permanently tied to the Dev channel only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following in a content.js

```
var newSpan = document.createElement("newSpan");
newSpan.id = "newSpan";
newSpan.style.fontSize = "25px";
newSpan.style.fontWeight = "bold";
newSpan.textContent = "******Banner******"
newSpan.style.color = "red";
var elemDiv = document.createElement('div');
elemDiv.style.cssText = 'width:100%;height:10%;background:rgb(255,255,255);text-align: center;';
elemDiv.appendChild(newSpan);

window.document.body.insertBefore(elemDiv, window.document.body.firstChild);
```