# Release schedule of chrome.infobars Chrome Toolbar API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, toolbar

I don't understand the status of the toolbar API in Chrome.

According to a 2013-06-24 answer to [How to make a toolbar in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681697/how-to-make-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome/17279590#17279590), there was a `chrome.experimental.infobars` API available in Chrome, and which was ready to become non-experimental.

However, if I go to the referenced web-page for the API, https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.infobars.html, there's a `302 Found` redirect to remove the `experimental.` part from the URL, and the API is not (/no longer) documented as being accessible under `experimental`, but it is said to only be available in the dev builds (`Availability:     Dev channel only.`), http://archive.is/yydlD.  What does this all mean?

- Is it now always available only in dev builds, or is it simply a matter of it being moved to non-experimental, with the upcoming stable release, hence being in dev now?
- If I want to develop a toolbar, can I still use `chrome.experimental.infobars` and regular stable Chrome?  Will this continue to work after the code from dev moves into stable?
- Will there be a [stable] build or two where it's available as both `chrome.exprimental.infobars` and `chrome.infobars`, to allow me some time to update my extension?

Answer (score 5):

Update (February 2015): The `chrome.infobars` API will be **removed** from Chrome in the future ([Chrome 42](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/chromium-extensions/Asv3vsDmVIY)?).

---

1. [`chrome.infobars`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/infobars.html) was [designed in 2008](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/info-bars), but it is only enabled on Developer builds and Canary only. It's not clear whether it will ever reach the stable channel, see 
   [Issue 39511: Launch Extension Infobars?](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39511) for more information.
2. `chrome.experimental.infobars` should no longer be used. It [has been removed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=259493) since Chrome 30. Use `chrome.infobars` instead.
3. You cannot upload extensions with the ["experimental"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.html) permission to the Chrome Web Store, so don't worry about breaking compatibility. The extensions being experimental means that their API can change without notice, or completely be removed. Provided that the API does not change, you can use a compatibility layer like like this:

   ```js
   if (!chrome.infobars && chrome.experimental && chrome.experimental.infobars) {
       chrome.infobars = chrome.experimental.infobars;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, it would seem like https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39511#c84 `r214692 moved this from experimental to restricted-to-trunk. We still need to decide if we want to launch it to stable.` and corresponding https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=214692&view=revision suggest what's going on here -- `chrome.experimental.infobars` was renamed to `chrome.infobars` in trunk on 2013-07-31; I guess I misunderstood the way that Chrome RE works -- they don't ever branch from trunk, but manually pick up individual patches for beta and then stable?  Weird.

Comment: @cnst The fate of the infobars API has been decided: It will be removed from Chrome.