# An alternative to -webkit-transform: transformY?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, toolbar

I'm creating a chrome extension that displays an iframe on the top of specific pages. This iframe is fixed and placed before opening body tag.

To reserve a place for this iframe, I shift down the body including fixed element using CSS :

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
```

It seems to work fine with many websites, but on some other website such as facebook it causes a problem. a scroll bar is shown on the right side.

Is there an alternative that I might try to avoid this problem . Any help would be appreciated[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just go one Node higher. And, you'll guess it, it's the `html` element. Unfortunately, I don't know a way to access it like the body: `document.body`.

But I found an easy way, use `document.body.parent`.

And there, you set the css property.

`document.body.parent.style.webkitTransform = 'translateY(40px)';`

Just besides, `margin-top` works too:

`document.body.parent.style.marginTop = '40px';`