# How to insert iframe/div to the top of browser body in javascript in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extension and did not know how to develop toolbar button in javascript/content script and want to fix it to the top of body(want to push body down). please help.

```
document.body.parent.style.webkitTransform ='translateY(40px)';

var div = document.createElement("div");

div.id="divs";
div.style.display='block';
div.style.width = "600px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.background = "#C2E2FF";


div.style.color = "grey";


div.innerHTML = "my div";

div.appendChild(btn1);
   document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
 document.getElementById("divs").style.fontStyle = 'italic';
 document.getElementById("divs").style.position = "fixed";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by means of a **[content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)** (see example below).

If you want to inject the toolbar to specific pages only, modify the **[match pattern](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)** appropriately. E.g.:

```
// To inject toolbar only to pages like `http://*.google.com/*`
// ...replace:
matches: ["*://*/*"]

// ...with:
matches: ["http://*.google.com/*"]
```

---

Below is the source code of a demo extension that injects a toolbar in every page that has a scheme of `http` or `https`.

**content.js:**

```
var toolbarHeight = 50;

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "myToolbar";
div.textContent = "I am the toolbar !";

var st = div.style;
st.display = "block";
st.top = "0px";
st.left = "0px";
st.width = "100%";
st.height = toolbarHeight + "px";
st.background = "#C2E2FF";
st.color = "grey";
st.fontStyle = "italic";
st.position = "fixed";

document.body.style.webkitTransform = "translateY(" + toolbarHeight + "px)";
document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "offline_enabled": true,

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*/*"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }]
}
```

See, also, this **[excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681697/how-to-make-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome#answer-17279590)** for an in-depth coverage of the subject.

Comment: Thanks for help but i want to make toolbar using div when i scroll down it should dock to top/ fix to top not disappear. when i scroll down then it is not fixed. help please

Comment: and i want it at all web pages ... i want to make customize toolbar button actually for that i making toolbar please help

Comment: See my updated answer (I changed the code somewhat to achieve what you want). If this answer helped you solve your problem, please **[mark it as "accepted"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**, so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.

Comment: no its not solving my problem div toolbar is still movable while scrolling :(

Comment: Are you sure you copied the new code ? I try it and it stays always visible at the top of the page. Try again copying the whole code from my updated answer.

Comment: Also, make sure you reload the extension and any page that was injected by the old code, in order to see the difference.

Comment: @user2853597: Did you try the update code ? Did it work for you ?