# How to get iFrame attached to the top bar of a loading page using content scripts?

Tags: html, css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I want to add an iFrame to the top of a web page by using the content scripts in chrome extensions.

The problem when I do something like this is:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });

var iFrame  = document.createElement ("iframe");
iFrame.src  = chrome.extension.getURL ("chrome.html");
iFrame.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
iFrame.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
iFrame.setAttribute("style", "border:none; width:100%; height:20%;  position: fixed;top: 10px; bottom: 10px;left: 10px;right: 10px;");
document.body.insertBefore (iFrame, document.body.firstChild);


function checkScroll()
{
    //remove the iframe
    //iFrame.parentNode.removeChild(iFrame);

    //or remove after 2 secs
    setTimeout(function(){ iFrame.parentNode.removeChild(iFrame); }, 2000);

    //off the scroll listener
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', checkScroll); 
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);
```

is that, sometimes the iframe loads below the web page. I want it to load from the top of the browser window. Also, it doesn't load in google search web pages. 
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you try my proposed solution below ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

A better option in this case is to add the iframe in `document.documentElement` (instead of in `document.body`) with a `static` position and then "shift" the body's CSS down (in order not to break functionality that might be bound to specific CSS values.

---

Below is the source code of a demo extension that injects a toolbar in every page that has a scheme of `http` or `https`.

**content.js:**

```
var height = '20%';
var padding = '10';

/* Create the iframe */
var iframe = document.createElement ('iframe');
iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL('/popup/popup.html');

/* Style the iframe */
var st = iframe.style;
st.border = 'none';
st.boxSizing = 'border-box';
st.height = height;
st.left = '0px';
st.padding = padding + 'px';
st.position = 'absolute';
st.top = '0px';
st.width = '100%';

/* Insert the iframe into the DOM */
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);

/* For a better UI experience convert relative height to absolute */
var heightInPixels = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(iframe).height);
st.height = (heightInPixels + (2 * padding)) + 'px';

/* Shift down the body's CSS (in order not to break anything) */
document.body.style.webkitTransform = 'translateY(' + st.height + ')';
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":    ["*://*/*"],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }]
}
```

<sub>If you want to inject the toolbar to specific pages only, modify the **[match pattern](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)** accordingly. E.g.:</sub>

```
// To inject toolbar only to pages like `http://*.google.com/*`
// ...replace:
matches: ["*://*/*"]

// ...with:
matches: ["http://*.google.com/*"]
```

---

See, also, this **[excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681697/how-to-make-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome#answer-17279590)** for an in-depth coverage of the subject.