# Google Chrome Extension Development

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension that would like to add a tab at the bottom of the page to manipulate DOM elements. Chrome 'manifest.json' file doesn't provide such feature. So how to do it or rather how does Firebug add a tab at the bottom of the Chrome?

Comment: **1.** Why not use Developer Tools (e.g. hit `F12`) ? **2.** Why not take a look at the source-code of Firebug ?

Comment: Looked at it. I don't want to use devTools because I want it to be an independent tab. And firebug source has the use of thier own libraries., implementing which seems very hard.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "independent tab" ?

Comment: That it should be a new window.. not like the popup looks! it should remain consistent even if the main screen scrolls or changes

Comment: I really don't get it. What happens to DevTools if you scroll the screen ? And what do you mean by "consistent" ? Not change its content ? And why would you need to see the content of a previosu page when the user navigates to a new page ? (Sorry, for the many questions, but I am trying to understand the problem in order to help. If you find tthem annoying, just don't answer :))

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! The layout should be like devTools but not its content because we cannot tell the user to go and open devTools everytime to access the extension's function. Consistent means the screen should not get minimized or invisible like popups.(when we click on main screen the popup disappears.) And the answer to the third question is, basically I am developing a functionality that shows updates in the new page or window based on the contents of main screen.

Comment: Did you try my proposed solution below ? Did it work for you ? If so, please, consider accepting/upvoting it.

Comment: Upvoting requires 15 reputation, which I, as a new user don't have.

Comment: Right ! I always forget about that :) Still, if this answer helped you with your problem, you can mark it as "accepted" (it is the check-mark on the left side next to the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest inserting a panel in every page through a content script. You can style it in order to appear at the bottom of the page and be always visible.

In order for it to retain its state between navigation from one page to another, you need to persist it some how (example use `chrome.storage` or a similar mechanism through the background page to persist the content (or whatever you need).

See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417991/how-to-get-iframe-attached-to-the-top-bar-of-a-loading-page-using-content-script#answer-20419005)** on how to insert (and style) a toolbar-like div or iframe in a page through a content script. (It is fixed to the top of the page, but you can easily modify the code to fix its position at the bottom.)