# What method should I use to make a Chrome toolbar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, toolbar

I have this small toolbar-like html page:

[image]

Currently, a user clicks on a link and this page opens in a new tab at the size shown. The user places this at the top of their screen then opens another tab below it taking up the rest of their screen. The user mainly works out of the larger window and interacts with this "toolbar" periodically.

This setup is obviously not ideal. Especially since you cant hide the chrome frame or the address bar which make the toolbar twice the height it needs to be.

What I'd like to do is make this an actual tool bar in Chrome, something like:
[image]

I did see [How to make a toolbar in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681697/how-to-make-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome) but I'm not sure which method would best suit my needs.

A few details:

- The toolbar must remain visible anytime its turned on/opened (as I
  understand it 'infobars' close themselves when not active? not 100%
  on that though)
- Navigating to a new page should not close the bar
- Navigating to a new page should not reload / render the bar (as I understand it using content scripts would reload the bar every time the user goes to a new page,)

I guess we could use a content scripts / local storage type solution to render the bar then set it up as it was on the previous page, seems hacky though.

**Am I missing a better way to do this?**

**Could anyone help me get started down the right path to achieve this result?**

Comment: There's no real toolbar in Chrome and you shouldn't make one. But if it is really a must, then shifting the whole page and injecting an iframe on top is the best IMO. I prefer an iframe so that the page's CSS won't interfere with the toolbar's.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Yeah, this is what I was leaning towards. This is accomplished using content scripts correct? Does the html in the iFrame get re-rendered every time a user clicks on a link in the main page with this method?

Comment: The bar won't be persistent since it's injected into the current page's dom, though I'm not sure if they had added methods that let it becomes persistent because the last time I made a toolbar in Chrome is quite a while ago.

Comment: I was afraid of that. That means I'll need to implement a system to keep up with the state of the bar. Thank you for confirming. Throw up an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A toolbar is an extension.

use [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).  The easiet way would be to download a sample from official google chrome's developper site.. and you will be able to change it the way you want.

Comment: If I set `persistent:true` for the background page in my extension, can I persist the "toolbar" created by my content script? Or will the html created by the content script be re-rendered every time a user clicks a link?

Comment: that's the drawback of this approach. The script will be rendered each time you click on a link. So to make your toolbar look more elegant you could apply a css rule which pushes down the content of the page with the height of your toolbar. For example, if your toolbar height is 30px you can apply a css rule that pushes down the page by 30px. It won't be really persistent But this way it will look far more elegant. When you apply the css rule, make sure it affects all elements of the page including the ones with position:fixed otherwise it won't work as expected on some sites such as twitter.

Comment: Ok, I've got it working so far. It loads the "toolbar" and sifts the main page content down with `var bodyStyle = document.body.style; var cssTransform = 'transform' in bodyStyle ? 'transform' : 'webkitTransform'; bodyStyle[cssTransform] = 'translateY(' + height + ')';` But as you alluded to, elements with position fixed are not shifted. Is there a way to affect those elements as well?

Comment: I was able to et this working perfectly using this method while using messagingand local storage to keep up with the state of the toolbar.