# Forcing elements in iframe to display over rest of page

Tags: css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I created a content script Chrome extension toolbar by following [@RobW's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17279590/1161463).

I'm now trying to get certain elements to overlay on the rest of the page, but currently they are only showing within the iframe.

For instance, an icon is clicked and shows a notification panel/tooltip. As you can see, it is cut off by the edge of the iframe:

[image: cutoff by edge of iframe]

Is there a way to change the CSS of the panel to hover on top of the rest of the page despite being in a separate iframe?

BTW, I made the height of the toolbar 143px, instead of the 43px you might expect of a toolbar, just so the issue would be more apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm fairly sure you can't do that with an `iframe`-based approach. That beats the purpose of `iframe` content isolation - imagine the [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) possibilites!

You will need to inject your UI into the document itself.

You probably went with an iframe-based approach because of possible clashes with the page's own CSS, for example. Thankfully, there's a modern tool to help with this - [Shadow DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the reason! I still need to be able to push down all other elements on the page, even existing fixed bars, while keeping mine pinned to the top. I've also seen other Chrome devs say there is an unresolved bug that prevents the Shadow DOM from working right in Chrome extensions.