# Injecting div on top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm writing an chrome extension which adds a 40px bar on top of all pages.
So in my content script I append this div to the page like this:

```
let overlayDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
overlayDiv.id = "myOverlayDIV";
overlayDiv.innerHTML = 'Content goes here'
document.body.insertBefore(overlayDiv, document.body.firstChild);
```

And my injected CSS looks like this:

```
#myOverlayDIV {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    z-index: 999999999 !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    height: 40px !important;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #9ccf1a
}
```

For most of pages this works as it should, but if you go to yahoo.com for example it looks like this:

https://prnt.sc/hbnibw

What should I change to make this DIV always on top of page?

Comment: Try with `position: fixed`.

Comment: @Tushar
In that case my div is overlapping the top of page, which becomes unusable -> take a look at this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/hbnnjg

Comment: Check if the site's styles take precedence over your CSS, in which case set the CSS inline on `style` attribute of the element or see [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12783217)

Comment: Another hack: Add these styles to body `position: relative; top: 40px;`. Use on own risk :p

Comment: @Tushar not working

Comment: this solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681697/how-to-make-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome#answer-17279590

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681697/how-to-make-a-toolbar-in-google-chrome#answer-17279590 this link contains the answer to my question

Comment: Actually not... it works fine on yahoo now, but there are some websites where it messes Y position of elements, like paypal for example:
https://prnt.sc/hbp4bm (notice the footer being moved up)